# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed while Form Post

Tags: iis, iis-express

I posted a request to payu server via form submit using angularjs now once payment is completed payu will return a response with hash.But when it hits my success page i get "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed".I found many solutions online but none of that solved my issue.What i understood is that static html do not allow post by default.But my staticFile in IIS is like below

> > Request Path : *
> >     
> >     Module : StaticFileModule
> >     Name : staticFile
> >     Request Restriction >Verb > All Verbs & Access > Script & Invoke > Files and folders

My question now in how to allow POST method for html page.I am using angular and if i change my success url to other than mine it works fine.I think there is some changes to be made to the web config but i tried my best but failed.Any help would be much appreciated.Also lets assume that the page successfully redirects to my success  page  how to capture the response that payu sends me online.

Thanks in advance if more input is needed from my side kindly ask in reply.

Comment: Here is the exact error message :  "The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used."

Answer (score 1):

It's not that HTML does not allow POST by default, it's that HTML does not handle POST, period. (Not even if the HTML file contains JavaScript.) POST sends data to a script that runs on your server, and the script has to be smart enough to know what to do with the data. HTML isn't that smart. The only thing your server can do with HTML is to send the HTML back to whatever is requesting it. You need a server-side script that knows how to parse payu's response, do something appropriate with the hash, and then generate some HTML to display in the user's browser.

Comment: Is there something i can do to change or allow post for html in IIS ?

Comment: It's not a question of allowing POST for HTML -- HTML is not capable of processing POST data. Even if you could allow POST to an HTML file, there is no server-side executable code in an HTML file, so you would just get a 503 server error instead.

Comment: so when payu sends response in POST method i should use c# coding like request.form[] and do some logics get and compare response then show some result in the browser ??